# how to push inside an object select a type and load a user to that type

Tags: javascript

my idea is to create an object array that has other objects as children
I explain

my idea is to be able to select a type and load a user to that type
I recommend a push

```
var items = [{"type":'1'}, {"type":'2'}]

input user = ['name':'mat','phone':'5555']

result = 
[{"type":'1','user':['name':'mat','phone':'5555']}, 
{"type":'2','user':['name':'nicol','phone':'888']}]
```

how could i do it
thanks

Comment: Why is `user` an array instead of an object?  I was expecting: `user = { name: 'mat', phone: '5555' }`.  i.e.:  `{ }`, not `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use {} instead of [] in user input. Because user would be an object, not an array.
I did the code below, but I don't know if it's what you wanted.
Iterated over the items array with map and added user attribute where the type matched with the inputed type.

```
var items = [{"type":'1'}, {"type":'2'}]

const type = '1'
const user = {"name": "mat", "phone": "5555"}

function addUserWhereType(items, type, user) {
    items.map(item => {
        if(item.type === type) {
            item.user = user
        }
    })
}

addUserWhereType(items, type, user)
console.log(items)
```

For more users the attibute will have to be an array (users). If the object item already have the field users, just push the user on users. If not, assign user to user field surrounded by [] to make users an array.

```
function addUserWhereType(items, type, user) {
    items.map(item => {
        if(item.type === type) {
            if(item.users.length === 0){
                item.users = [user]
            } else {
                item.users.push(user)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: and if I wanted to have several users in the same type ?